# Test UITextField text string to only contain alphanumeric characters

Tags: ios, swift, forms, validation, unicode

Im trying to complete form validation in Swift and cant find a way of testing for only Alphanumeric characters in a UITextField.text.

Ive found NSCharacterSet to help test if at least 1 letter has been entered (so far):

```
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
let letters = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()

//Check username contains a letter
   if (username.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters) == nil) {
        getAlert("Error", message: "Username must contain at least 1 letter")
    }
```

Now i just need a way to validate that only numbers, letters (maybe even underscores and dashes) to be entered. Loads of stuff out there for Obj-C but I need a SWIFT solution please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the inversion of your accepted set is present:

```
if username.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(letters.invertedSet) != nil {
    print("invalid")
}
```

`letters` should probably be `alphanumericCharacterSet()` if you want to include numbers as well.

If you want to accept underscores or more chars, you will probably have to create a character set by your own. But the inversion logic will stay the same.

Comment: And you can build a character set that is the union (combination) of numbers, lower case letters, and upper case letters. Let's call it alphanumericSet. Then use this approach to say "does the field text contain any characters not in the set alphanumericSet"

Comment: @luk2302 this didnt work :( I was still able to log in using the string "a_12-()11"

Comment: @Chris then you used the code in the wrong way. Note that I inverted the logic of the `if` - whenever you fulfill the if-condition you have a valid username as opposed to your code where fulfilling the if-condition meant an invalid one.

Comment: let alphaNum = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet(); if username.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(alphaNum.invertedSet) == nil) {
            getAlert("oops!", message: "Letters and numbers only")
        }; @luk2302 Ive use it like this and it doesnt work, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chris i changed the code, check again, you had to invert the if logic.

Answer (score 3):

Though it's late to answer, but this answer might be useful to someone.

This is simple and worked like a charm for me.

Swift 3:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    /// 1. replacementString is NOT empty means we are entering text or pasting text: perform the logic
    /// 2. replacementString is empty means we are deleting text: return true
    if string.characters.count > 0 {
        var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics

        /// add characters which we need to be allowed
        allowedCharacters.insert(charactersIn: " -") // "white space & hyphen" 

        let unwantedStr = string.trimmingCharacters(in: allowedCharacters)
        return unwantedStr.characters.count == 0
    }

    return true
}
```

Note: This will work for pasting strings into the text field as well. Pasted string will not be displayed in text field if it contains any unwanted characters.